# How can I convert the machine code of an exe to a string of 1s and 0s with Node.js?

Tags: node.js

The following code tries to parse the contents of an exe so the result is a bunch of unknown characters and bits of strings:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile( __dirname + '/test.exe', function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  console.log(data.toString());
});
```

But how can I get it to output a string of 1s and 0s instead? I'm trying to generate the machine code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` parameter in `readFile`'s callback is a buffer, you can iterate over it to get each byte (which is a number) and convert it to its binary representation like that:

```
  for (const byte of data.values()) {
    console.log(byte.toString(2).padStart(8, '0'));
  }
```

The call to padStart() at the end is used to make all numbers have the same length

By the way, if ever you want to parse a small file this code is fine, but if you want to parse a much bigger file (let's say 3Go for example), I recommend you to use streams, else you will run out of memory pretty fast :)